# Cannot upload a file in Asp.Net Core 3.1 API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, create-react-app, multipartform-data

In a React App:

```
const onInputFileChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    const file = files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    
    const uri = "path/to/my/endpoint/myc/12/upload";
    const fetchOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: [["Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"]],
        mode: "cors",
        body: formData
    };
    
    fetch(uri, fetchOptions).then(res => console.log(res));
};

return (
    <input
        onChange={onInputFileChange}
        type="file"
        accept={".xslx"}
    />
);
```

I am sending an Excel file. I have the following controller:

```
[HttpPost("myc/{id}/upload")]
//[Consumes("multipart/form-data")] // This line is commented intentionally
public ActionResult UploadExcelFile(string id)
{
    var form = this.Request.Form; // Exception here!!!
    return Ok();
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in the method (beginning), I see it is hit. When I step further in the first line, an exception is thrown when reading `Form`:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Incorrect Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```

---

#### Attempt I

If I remove the comment in the attribute `Consumes`, I never get to the method; instead I get a 415 Unsupported media Type.

#### Attempt II

If I set the controller's `Consumes` and the request's `Content-Type` both to: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, I get the same error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Incorrect Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```

#### Attempt III

If I change the controller like this:

```
[HttpPost("myc/{id}/upload")]
//[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public ActionResult UploadExcelFile(string id, IFormFile file)
{
    var form = this.Request.Form;
    return Ok();
}
```

I get a 400 Bad Request and do not hit the method.

---

How exactly am I supposed to make this work?

Comment: Do you know how you got this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just omit `Content-Type` header in request and browser will set a correct one for you. Since correct value for `FormData` is `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=something` you need to let browser to set valid boundary value for you.

```
const file = files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);

const uri = "path/to/my/endpoint/myc/12/upload";
const fetchOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    body: formData
};

fetch(uri, fetchOptions).then(res => console.log(res));
```